# How to replace the string with defalut date?

Tags: c#

I have this code.

```
  string ED= collection["ED"].Replace(string.Empty,"1/1/2011").Split(',').ToString();
```

when I do this I am geting this error.

```
String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue
```

is that something I am doig wrong here?

thanks

Comment: You cannot use `String.Empty` as the string to replace. You need to have a string that is at least 1 character in length

Comment: Yes its collection arry reggie.

Comment: It looks like the error message told you *exactly* what you're doing wrong. What are you still confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.Replace` takes replace all insatances of the first argument with the second argument. So `"abcabcabc".Replace("a", "z")` becomes `"zbczbczbc"`.

Replacing all instances of the empty string is going to lead to an infinate loop of replacements. `"".Replace(string.Empty, "a")` replaces the empty string with "a", but there's still an empty string before and after the a, which needs to get replaced and so we have "aaa", but there's still an empty string at the begining and end of the string, as well as between the a's, so replacing those we get "aaaaaaa" etc.

Do you actually mean to use the default date if the value is empty? In which case you want to do something like:

```
var temp = collection["ED"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp)) {
    temp = "1/1/2011";
}
string ED = temp.Split(',').ToString();
```

Comment: temp.Split(',').ToString(); will return "System.String[]" regardless of what value temp contains. The Split() method converts the string object to an array of strings.

Comment: @Andy Rose True. I hadn't even thought about that part of it, had just copied that verbatim from the OP.

Comment: I think `string ED = string.Join("", temp.Split(','))` would do. I'll wait until I've actually tried it before I update.

Comment: Join would work on an array but I guess the next question would be why not just use .Replace(",", "") to remove unwanted commas?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of the Replace method cannot be an empty string.
[See the exceptions section of this msdn article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)
Without knowing a bit more about what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to help any further. As it stands if the Replace method were to succeed then the Split method would convert the string to an array and then the ToString method would return "System.String[]". I doubt this is the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

oldValue is the first parameter of `Replace()` so I'm guessing you can't pass `string.Empty` to that

Comment: no need to guess. If it were valid what would it to, now that would be a stack overflow.